# Need to change OwnerId field to Queue's Id if the creator of the record isn't from this Queue

Tags: soql, map, queue, set

I need to change OwnerId of created record to Queue Id, if the record is created not by User from this Queue. If creator is from this Queue, just leave our OwnerId field unchanged. How can I do that?

```
public static void helper(List<Object__c> newList) {

    Group groupQueue = [SELECT Id FROM Group WHERE Name='Our Queue' AND Type = 'Queue'];
    Map<Id, GroupMember> groupMembersMap = new Map<Id, GroupMember>([SELECT UserOrGroupId FROM GroupMember WHERE GroupId =: groupQueue.Id]);
    Set<Id> recordIds = groupMembersMap.keySet();

    for(Object__c obj: newList){

            if(!recordIds.contains(obj.OwnerId)){
                obj.OwnerId = recordIds;
            }    
    }
}
```

If a Obj record isn't created by 'X' user - reassign it to the Our Queue.

Comment: what will happen if user is a member of 2 queues. which queue you will consider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `groupQueue.Id` instead of set `recordIds`

```
public static void helper(List<Object__c> newList) {
    Group groupQueue = [
        select Id
        from Group
        where Name = 'Our Queue' and Type = 'Queue'
        ];          
    Set<Id> queueMembersIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(GroupMember member :[
        select UserOrGroupId 
        from GroupMember
        where GroupId = :groupQueue.Id){
        queueMembersIds.add(member.UserOrGroupId);
    }

    for(Object__c obj: newList){
        if(!queueMembersIds.contains(obj.CreatedById)){
            obj.OwnerId = groupQueue.Id;
        }    
    }
}
```

Comment: No. I need a member.Id from this groupQueue. How can I take that?

Comment: there could be more then one queue member. Which one you want to use?

Comment: Ah. Sorry. Yes, your answer is right. Thank you) But I need to change Owner to the Queue just if creater (CreatedById) of this object is not from this Queue.

Comment: just change `OwnerId` to `CreatedById` in if condition. I have updated my answer

Comment: It change it anyway. My user is from Role that relates to Our Queue. And even if this user is object's creator, it anyway change the owner :(

Comment: can you please update your initial question with full requirements and example

Comment: I change it. Hope it's better now.